# Telnet.read.until function doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to telnet to a Brocade router and the python script is sending out error.... Not sure what is wrong here. Have tried a debug but cant make it working. I believe it's prompt issue. I appreciate if anyone has suggestion how to get it work.

Note: This is Python 3.0

```
import getpass
import sys
import telnetlib

HOST = "1.1.1.1"
user = "admin"
password = "password"
port = "23"

telnet = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

telnet.read_until("sw0 login:,3")

telnet.write(admin + "\r")
if password:
    telnet.read_until("Password: ")
    telnet.write(password + "\n")

tn.write("term len 0" + "\n")
telnet.write("sh ver br\n")
telnet.write("exit\n")


ERROR:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\milan\Desktop\telnetNew.py", line 13, in <module>
    telnet.read_until("Username :,3")
  File "C:\Python33\lib\telnetlib.py", line 299, in read_until
    return self._read_until_with_select(match, timeout)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\telnetlib.py", line 352, in _read_until_with_select
    i = self.cookedq.find(match)
TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API


This is my prompt after logging manually using telnet port 23 and this is what i expected command to work.
_________________________________________________________________________________



Network OS (sw0)
xxxxxxxxxx


sw0 login: xxxxx
Password:  xxxxx

WARNING: The default password of 'admin' and 'user' accounts have not been changed.

Welcome to the Brocade Network Operating System Software
admin connected from 10.100.131.18 using console on sw0
sw0# sh ver


sw0#
```

Comment: looks like it might be issue with the python2 - 3 conversion and str to unicode conversion.  There was a bug in telnetlib a while back that looks like it was fixxed, so not sure where to go next

Comment: Thanks. You meant to say Telnetlib itself has issue in python3?

Answer (score 6):

In looking at the docs, it appears that telnetlib want a bytestr, not a Str.  so try this., which should convert everything to bytes as opposed to Str

```
import sys
import telnetlib

HOST = "1.1.1.1"
user = "admin"
password = "password"
port = "23"

telnet = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST,port)
telnet.read_until(b"login: ")

telnet.write(admin.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
telnet.read_until(b"Password: ")
telnet.write(password.encode('ascii') + b"\n")

tn.write(b"term len 0\n")
telnet.write(b"sh ver br\n")
telnet.write(b"exit\n")
```

--edit--  I installed python and tried this against one of my routers.  Changing the username/password to my credentials I was able to login fine.   ( I removed the password check and the getpass as they where not being used, being that your code has them hardcoded).  It looks like you copied the 2.x example, but the 3.x requires the buffer compatible ones  without the b"  i Get this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 5, in <module>
    telnet.read_until("login: ")
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python32/3.2.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/telnetlib.py", line 293, in read_until
    return self._read_until_with_poll(match, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python32/3.2.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/telnetlib.py", line 308, in _read_until_with_poll
    i = self.cookedq.find(match)
TypeError: expected an object with the buffer interface
```

with the b"  I get

```
[~] /usr/local/bin/python3.2 foo.py
b'\r\n\r\nThis computer system including  all related equipment, network devices\r\n(specifically  including  Internet  access),  are  provided  only  for\r\nauthorized use.  All computer
```

which shows it is working..  what errors are you getting now

Comment: Thanks. However i see syntax error. import getpass
import sys
import telnetlib

HOST = "10.20.23.65"
user = "admin"
password = "password"
port = "23"

telnet = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

telnet.read_until(b"user: ")

telnet.write(admin.encode('ascii') + b"\r")
tn.write(user.encode("admin" + "\r")
         
 if password:
    telnet.read_until(b"password: ")
    telnet.write(password.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
    tn.write(password.encode("password" + "\n")

tn.write(b"term len 0\n")
telnet.write(b"sh ver br\n")
telnet.write(b"exit\n")

Comment: The main purpose to issue show commands into telnet seesion using python. it failed and send syntax error at "if password:"

Comment: all I did was copy your code and add the b to id them as bytes.  in your code after adding the b do you get the same error about buffer API or a new error?

Answer (score 4):

```
import telnetlib , socket


class TELNET(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.tn = None
        self.username = "root"
        self.password = "12345678"
        self.host = "10.1.1.1"
        self.port = 23
        self.timeout = 5
        self.login_prompt = b"login: "
        self.password_prompt = b"Password: "

    def connect(self):
        try :
            self.tn = telnetlib.Telnet(self.host,self.port,self.timeout)
        except socket.timeout :
            print("TELNET.connect() socket.timeout")

        self.tn.read_until(self.login_prompt, self.timeout) 
        self.tn.write(self.username.encode('ascii') + b"\n")

        if self.password :
            self.tn.read_until(self.password_prompt,self.timeout)
            self.tn.write(self.password.encode('ascii') + b"\n")

    def write(self,msg):
        self.tn.write(msg.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
        return True


    def read_until(self,value):
        return self.tn.read_until(value)


    def read_all(self):
        try :
            return self.tn.read_all().decode('ascii')
        except socket.timeout :
            print("read_all socket.timeout")
            return False

    def close(self):
        self.tn.close()
        return True


    def request(self,msg):
        self.__init__()
        self.connect()
        if self.write(msg) == True :
            self.close()
            resp = self.read_all()
            return resp
        else :
            return False

telnet = TELNET()

#call request function 

resp = telnet.request('ps www') # it will be return ps output
print(resp)
```

## That code works on python3

Comment: and perhaps some explanation if possible..?

Answer (score 2):

Most of these answers are great in-depth explanations and I found them a little hard to follow. The short answer is that the Sample code is wrong on the Python 3x site.

to fix this, instead of 
' telnet.read_until("Username :,3")'
use
' telnet.read_until(b"Username :,3")'

Answer (score 1):

Like the other answers say, the problem is that Telnetlib expects byte strings. In Python 2 the `str` type is a byte string (a string of binary data) whereas it's a unicode string in Python 3 and a new `bytes` type that represents binary data in the same was as `str` did in Python 2.

The upshot of this is that you need to convert your `str` data into `bytes` data when using Telnetlib in Python 3. I have some code that works in both Python2 and Python3 that I thought worth sharing.

```
class Telnet(telnetlib.Telnet,object):
    if sys.version > '3':
        def read_until(self,expected,timeout=None):
            expected = bytes(expected, encoding='utf-8')
            received = super(Telnet,self).read_until(expected,timeout)
            return str(received, encoding='utf-8')

        def write(self,buffer):
            buffer = bytes(buffer, encoding='utf-8')
            super(Telnet,self).write(buffer)

        def expect(self,list,timeout=None):
            for index,item in enumerate(list):
                list[index] = bytes(item, encoding='utf-8')
            match_index, match_object, match_text = super(Telnet,self).expect(list,timeout)
            return match_index, match_object, str(match_text, encoding='utf-8')
```

You then instantiate the new `Telnet` class instead of `telnetlib.Telnet`. The new class overrides methods in Telnetlib to perform conversion from `str` to `bytes` and `bytes` to `str` so that the problem just goes away.

Of course, I've only overriden the methods that I was using, but it should be clear from the example how to extend the idea to other methods. Basically, you need to use

```
 bytes(str_string, encoding='utf-8')
```

and

```
str(bytes_string, encoding='utf-8')
```

My code is valid Python 2 and 3 so will work unmodified with either interpreter. When in Python2 the code that overrides the methods is skipped over, effectively ignored. If you don't care for backwards compatibility you can remove the condition that checks for the Python version.