# Error message when running telnet in python shell

Tags: python, byte, telnet, typeerror

Below is a minimal example of my code, which If you run, should recreate the problem I have. One thing I have encounter that the error does not appear if my raspberry pi (the thing I am using teller to connect to) is turned off or the internet cable is unplugged.

```
#IMPORTS
import time
import telnetlib
import sys
import getpass


#TELNET
user = input("Please Enter Your Username: ")
time.sleep(0.4)
pass_ = input("Please Enter Your Password: ")

bot = telnetlib.Telnet("192.168.1.128")
bot.read_until("login: ".encode(),  timeout=None)
bot.write(user + "\n")
bot.read_until("Password: ".encode(),  timeout=None)
bot.write(pass_ + "\n")
bot.write("cd PiBits/ServoBlaster")
```

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kiancross/Desktop/PROJECTS/RASPBERRY_PI/ROBOT/CONTROLLER_GUI/RPi_BOT_CONTROLLER.py", line 17, in <module>
    bot.write(user + "\n")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/telnetlib.py", line 289, in write
    if IAC in buffer:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not bytes
```

I was running the following code which you can see in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23221123/why-do-i-get-this-error-message-when-using-telnet-in-python-shell) post but as you can see from the answer I changed it to the code above which resulted in the above error message.

I should say that the code is no where near finished and a lot of things are just to test until I get telnet working!

I have tried the fix for the older version of python mentioned in [this](http://mechanix-tips.blogspot.co.uk/2008/12/python-telnetlib-typeerror-in-requires.html) post.

I have used `print(type(user))` to see what kind the variables are and they are strings. I have tried `bot.write((user + "\n").encode(latin-1))` as shown in this fix, but the error message still appears. I have also tried encoding in unicode. I understand that part of that line is encoded wrong but I don't know if it is the variables or the `"\n"`. I have tried doing `bot.write(user + b"\n")` but this get rid of the error.

If anybody has any other methods that could stop this error, I would greatly appreciate them.

Thanks

P.S Im running on python 3.4.0

**EDIT**

I have tried this:

```
bot = telnetlib.Telnet("192.168.1.128")
bot.write(user + "\n".encode('ascii'))
bot.read_until(b"Password: ")
bot.write((pass_ + "\n").encode('ascii'))
```

But I still get the same error.

When I do:

```
bot = telnetlib.Telnet("192.168.1.128")
bot.read_until(b"login: ")
bot.write(user + b"\n")
bot.read_until(b"Password: ")
bot.write(pass_ + b"\n")
```

I get a different error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kiancross/Desktop/PROJECTS/RASPBERRY_PI/ROBOT/CONTROLLER_GUI/RPi_BOT_CONTROLLER.py", line 23, in <module>
    bot.write(user + b"\n")
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
```

All the error seem to say that It needs to be a string but my variables are already strings.

Thanks

Comment: Are you really going to post every error you get here as your code slowly moves through various stages of people fixing it? Have you stepped through your code? You know exactly what the error is and where it is... what conclusions have you come to?

Comment: P.S. you'll end up question banning yourself if you [delete questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220040/error-message-when-running-telnet-in-python-shell) and then re-post in order to get more attention. There's a lot of advice [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions) on getting attention for your questions.

Comment: The error message says that you're passing bytes, not a string, to `bot.write()`. The obvious thing to try first is to convert the bytes that into a string; the blog post that you've linked to says the same thing. I wasn't, however, asking you to place 10 different bits of code. I was asking you to flesh out your question from "here's my code-dump and error - fix it for me". You've now mentioned that you're trying to fix for earlier Python builds but still encounter the error? Are you then using Python 3? Python 2.7? What fix were you trying? Where are you trying it?

Comment: @crossboy007 - you'd be surprised at how worthwhile it is to try listing the things you've done. The process of trying to explain what you've done and what you understand frequently gets you to solve the problem on your own. And if you *don't* solve the problem because you truly don't understand something then you'll find legions of people willing to help. When you post the exact same code with almost the exact same problem the volunteers will quickly lose patience with you. If you want to pay someone to fix your code, there are plenty of us who are willing to take your money and fix it.

Comment: Don't tell _me_ @crossboy007 - tell everyone! [edit] your question to include all the information you have. If you'd included this in the first place then you wouldn't have a useless answer. For instance, your question can be: I'm trying to use telnet, this is a [_minimal_ example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of my code. I get error X. Blog post Y suggests fix Z, which I've implemented as A. I get error B. Blog post C suggests D but thing E happens instead. Having stepped through the function it appears as though I am passing a string so why do I get this error. P.S. I'm on Python 3.2.

Comment: _I have tried doing bot.write(user + b"\n") but this get rid of the error._ - so what's the problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The telnet interface probably wants to work in bytes not Unicode. I have tested this code on Python3 and it avoids the error:

```
import telnetlib
bot = telnetlib.Telnet("127.0.0.1", 22)
user = "dobbs"
bot.write((user + "\n").encode('ascii'))
print(bot.read_all())
```

Comment: It works for me. Please update your code to show what you've done.

Comment: Your problem is that you're encoding the newline to bytes, but you need to encode the entire string after joining it.

Comment: You are not doing it right. There is a difference between `(user + '\n'.encode('ascii'))` and `(user + '\n').encode('ascii')`. Show your current code.

Comment: Please notice the difference between that code and my code.