# Python3 telnet code stays quiet after launching, does not initiate the command to router

Tags: python, telnet, router

I need to Telnet into my router and issue a reboot command on it. And it has to be achieved with Python. Here's the code I've got:

```
import sys
import telnetlib

HOST = "192.168.1.254"
user = "Administrator"
password = "xxxxxxxx"
port = "23"

telnet = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST,port)
telnet.read_until(b"login: ")

telnet.write(admin.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
telnet.read_until(b"Password: ")
telnet.write(password.encode('ascii') + b"\n")

telnet.write(b"system reboot\n")
telnet.close()
```

When I'm initating it in command prompt it'd just stay blank, no errors whatsoever. It's as if it's loading something for so long, but the router would not reboot. The script sort of hangs.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Must it produce output? It just reboots and that's all

Comment: Sorry, my English isn't so good, so I might explain myself wrongly. You're right, it does not have to produce output. But the router does not reboot, though I've told it to "system reboot".

Comment: Edited ur question read edit carefully

Comment: What's `admin` in `telnet.write(admin.encode('ascii') + b"\n")`? Did you mean `user`?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to build my code on this user's example, since he said he got it working: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20485573/3596479. It would be logical to use "user.encode" though. Which I tried, but it didn't help.

Comment: Are the username & password in your script **identical** to the username & password you use to log into your router through its Web interface?

Comment: Yes, they are identical. I'm actually doing this whole thing for testing and learning purposes, so router has a default config and default user/pass.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue today, 1.5 years after your question. In my case, the issue was resolved by removing the extra space, i.e.:

```python
telnet.read_until(b"Password: ") # note the space before "
```

becomes:

```
telnet.read_until(b"Password:") # no space before "
```

It seems, the problem exists because of the extra space that is not output by telnet serve and thus read_until is not able to find the specified string.

Answer (score -1):

To my mind, there is something wrong with string passed to router. They must not be byte (the `b` prefix is not needed). Try removing it. String encoding also seems strange.

Comment: `b` as a string prefix means that it's a __byte__ string. In Python 2 `b` does nothing, but in Python 3 all strings are by default Unicode, so you need to use the `b` to get a Python 2 style string.

Comment: @PM2Ring, doesn't Python3 have `telnetlib` that can deal with 'not-byte' strings, as usual?

Comment: Removing "b" in front of "system reboot" did not help either.

Comment: Perhaps not; the [example code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/telnetlib.html#telnet-example) in the official telnetlib docs for Python 3 uses explicit `b` strings. FWIW, I don't use Python3, but I have succesfully used telnetlib in Python 2 to telnet into my ADSL modem. The `b` strings makes sense IMHO, since the telnet protocol uses ASCII strings and so I'd expect it to get confused if you talked to it with Unicode.